# set number of trees in R ~ Caret package

Tags: r, tree, classification, random-forest, r-caret

I am currently wondering on the way to set 10 trees using the random forest algorithm from the Caret package, and hope an assistance could be obtained:

below is my syntax:

```
tr <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 20)

fit<-train(y ~.,method="rf",data=example, trControl=tr)
```

Following researches on http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomForest/docs/randomForest

Setting either `n=10`
as argument in `randomForest()`  or  `n.trees` in case of using `gbm` could have merely helped, but I am interested in the `Caret` package.

Any feedback would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Caret's `train()` uses the `randomForest()` function when you specify `method = "rf"` in the `train` call.

You simply need to pass `ntree = 10` to `train` which then will be passed on to `randomForest()`.

Therefore, your call would look like this:

`fit <- train(y ~., method="rf",data=example, trControl=tr, ntree = 10)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I appreciate. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

For interest to anyone in my position who landed here while using ranger method of random forrest (Google still directed me here when specifying "ranger" in my search term) use num.trees.

```
num.trees = 20
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `ntree` is a parameter you are looking for